# How to re-register (after unregistering it) an android device to firebase push notification?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I have just implemented my push notification on Android with Firebase.
Firebase is registering the device on the app start.
I wanted to add a switch that enables/disables the notifications inside of the app.
I could unregister the user by calling `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();` but I couldn't figure out how to register the user back.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: why can't you regenerate a new token so that the device will again get notifications.

Comment: because firebase is not giving this possibility (from what I have seen sofar).

Comment: there is an overrided method ontokenrefresh, i think that can make it done :)

Comment: that's triggered when the token is refreshed... it doesn't generate any token or register any device...

Answer (score 1):

You Could use this approach to enable/disable notification.

1.Send DeviceId with Token at the start of app and exchange with Server.

2.Server Side script if you already have deviceId then update FCM token linked with DeviceId.

3.When You want to stop Notification Disable at Sever Side Script with a Flag for corresponding device and same for enabling.

Hope it help..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not asking how to register/unregister my devices on my own backend (or any third party backend) but on Firebase. Once the device is unregistered from Firebase the token will be null and there's noway -so far- to generate it programmatically... Additionally, I am not using GCM but FCM...